# Index was outside the bounds of the array in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Want to create shopping cart for my site , i have this below lines for my shopping cart controller:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        repository = new Repository();
        // Retrieve the album from the database
        var addedProduct = repository.FindProductByIdSingle(id);

        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

This below classes for my shopping cart model in model folder:

Cart.cs

```
public class Cart
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

Order.cs

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

OrderDetails.cs

```
public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public virtual Product product { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

ProductEntities.cs

```
public class ProductEntities: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}
```

ShoppingCart.cs

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
     ProductEntities storeDB = new ProductEntities();
    string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";

     public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }

    // Helper method to simplify shopping cart calls
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(Controller controller)
    {
        return GetCart(controller.HttpContext);
    }

    public void AddToCart(Product product)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and album instances
        var cartItem  = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && c.ProductId == product.Id);

        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            cartItem = new Cart
            {
                ProductId = product.Id,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Count = 1,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                Product = product                  
            };
            storeDB = new ProductEntities();
            storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);// Error Error
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity
            cartItem.Count++;
        }
        // Save changes
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I Run Project for first time the below line in ShoppingCart class throw this Exception:

> storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);// Error Error
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But some times throwing this Exception:

> Index Out Of Bound Of Array

And this Below line for my stacktrace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataOptimization.GetCSpaceAssociationType(AssociationType osAssociationType) +38
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.FindRelationshipSet(ObjectContext context, EntitySet entitySet, EdmType& relationshipType, RelationshipSet& relationshipSet) +202
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AttachContext(ObjectContext context, EntitySet entitySet, MergeOption mergeOption) +312
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AttachContext(ObjectContext context, MergeOption mergeOption) +178
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.CreateRelatedEnd(RelationshipNavigation navigation, RelationshipMultiplicity sourceRoleMultiplicity, RelationshipMultiplicity targetRoleMultiplicity, RelatedEnd existingRelatedEnd) +627
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipFixer`2.System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IRelationshipFixer.CreateSourceEnd(RelationshipNavigation navigation, RelationshipManager relationshipManager) +116
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedEnd(RelationshipNavigation navigation, IRelationshipFixer relationshipFixer) +129
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity) +93
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach) +231
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach) +210
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach) +164
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity) +521
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__c() +98
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +355
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +200
>      System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +131
>      MobileShop.Models.ShoppingCart.AddToCart(Product product) in d:\Projects\Asp.net\MobileShop\MobileShop\Models\ShoppingCart.cs:46
>      MobileShop.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.AddToCart(Int32 id) in d:\Projects\Asp.net\MobileShop\MobileShop\Controllers\ShoppingCartController.cs:40
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +161
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Note: when i add new cart to cartItem, product have factorDetail fielde that is null so Does it matter?

Note 2 : I Using this tutorial [Part 8: Shopping Cart with Ajax Updates | The ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8)

So how i fixed this Exception?

Comment: Which of these `storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem)` does the debugger tell you is null? `storeDB`, `Carts`, or `cartItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse this will throw exception. because you are you are instantiating a new ProductEntities class just before adding cart to db.

`storeDB = new ProductEntities();
storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);`

remove this `storeDB = new ProductEntities();`
you have already instantiated ProductEntities() on first line of code in ShoppingCart.cs

because creating a new instance will forgot all your object in previous context.
and new context has null value in cartitem to add.